# How do I "date-protect" my application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've built a little WindowsForm app from a standard beginner's tutorial.  The kind where you use controls like buttons and textboxes to add 2 numbers and have the result show up in a textbox.

Anyways, I want to make it so that when a user clicks on my .exe, it checks against my built-in expiration date before even launching the program/window.  That is, if my expiration date were today Oct. 30, nothing happens, no window form even shows up.  However, if my expiration date were to be Oct. 31, everything proceeds normally and windows and forms show up.  But, tomorrow on Oct. 31 (expiration date) and any day after tomorrow if the user were to run my .exe, nothing would happen.

I think my code would look something like this:

```
DateTime expiration = new DateTime(2013, 10, 31) //Oct. 31, 2013
If (DateTime.Today < expiration) //proceed normally
else // do nothing, nothing happens for the user
```

From the tutorial, most of my understanding is confined to code written inside the public Form1 : Form part of the code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Where would I insert code to check today's date against my expiration date so that no forms are loaded?

Comment: I do hope you're not trying to do this to enforce some kind of licence, like a free trial period or something.

Comment: Consider pinging an internet service - this is circumvented quite easily by changing the PS system time.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten not the worst offense. I worked with a guy who snuck one in when he was made redundant. Application didnt work on Feb 29. Took ages to debug.

Comment: I'll also add that you should probably at least give a message box with "license expired" or similar.  If you just do *nothing*, your user will go mad trying to click your app over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want this in the `Program.cs` file, here's a simple example

```
static class Program
{
    static DateTime expiration = new DateTime(2013, 10, 31);

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (DateTime.Today < expiration.Date) 
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

However, just bare in mind that this isn't really the recommended approach for enforcing an expirable application (e.g. trial software). Generally it's better to use some form of robust licensing system, hard-coding the date into the exe is by no means full-proof and easily exploitable.

Comment: Generally it's better to use some form of robust licensing system, hard-coding the date into the exe . how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Look at `Program.cs` in your Solution Explorer. You can add this code inside the `Main` function, and call `Application.Exit()` to leave the application if the condition you have specified hasn't been met.

Answer (score 2):

I won't recommend using "Local Time" for this because user can take the freedom of changing it anytime.

Probably you'll have to get current time from some "Time server"

```
private static readonly DateTime expiration = new DateTime(2013, 10, 31);
static void Main()
{
    DateTime currentTime = GetTimeFromSomeTimeServer();//Implement yourself
    if (currentTime.Date >= expiration.Date)
    {
        return;//Dont run the app
    }
    //Rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: But then what if the computer does not have internet? Double edged sword.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  I am okay with not letting the program run if the computer does not have internet.

Comment: @gunr2171 You've to decide then. It is your call to allow the app to proceed or not.

Comment: @phan Then go for it. :)

Comment: Ah the wonders that ILDasm -> delete a few lines -> ILAsm can do :-)

Comment: @Kris What does that mean?

Comment: @phan That it would take me, and many others, less than five minutes to remove that code from your application. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx

Comment: @Kris LOL, OK!  If you really want the tutorial-led fancy adding machine that I've built have at it!  For me, this exercise is like putting a lock on my door.  Locksmiths like you can easily open it, but it keeps most of the people that I associate with, out.

Comment: @phan Sure, fair enough. I just wanted you to be aware of the situation. Don't use this for adding machines that add real money into the user's accounts :-)